# The type or namespace 'Customer' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am extremely new to APS.NET, so forgive my easy question.

I have created a new Model under the Models directory named 'Customer.cs' with the following content:

```
namespace PetParadiseHotel.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Zipcode { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }
}
```

After that I created a controller called 'CustomerController.cs' under the Controllers directory where I want to hardcode a new Customer just to see how it works:

```
public ActionResult Details()
        {
            var c1 = new Customer
            {
                CustomerID = 1,
                FirstName = "Susan",
                LastName = "Peterson",
                Address = "Borgergade 45",
                Zipcode = "8000",
                City = "Aarhus",
                Email = "supe@xmail.dk",
                Phone = "21212121"
            };
            return View(c1);
        }
```

But for some reason I get this error:

> The type or namespace name 'Customer' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a reference `using PetParadiseHotel.Models` on top in your controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reference the namespace of that class.  Add this to the top of your controller:

```
using PetParadiseHotel.Models;
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you! There are always a few annoying details you have to deal with when starting a new language :)

Comment: No problem.  If you plan to spend much time doing .NET development, I suggest investing in a copy of Resharper...it will suggest fixes for issues like this and save you time in a thousand other ways.